# Magento 2: get attribute set name for a product in phtml file

Tags: magento2, product, attributes, product-attribute, attribute-set

I try to get the attribute-set name for a product in a phtml file.
In magento 1 the code for this is:

```
$id = 2;
$product = Mage::getModel(‘catalog/product’)->getCollection->load($id);
$attributeSetModel = Mage::getModel("eav/entity_attribute_set");
$attributeSetModel->load($product->getAttributeSetId());
$attributeSetName = $attributeSetModel->getAttributeSetName();
echo $attributeSetName;
```

i have the attribute_set_id, but i try to get the name.

Which one is equivalent for magento 2?
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For product page use below code :

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');
$attributeSet = $objectManager->create('Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeSetRepositoryInterface');
$attributeSetRepository = $attributeSet->get($product->getAttributeSetId());
$attribute_set_name = $attributeSetRepository->getAttributeSetName();
echo $attribute_set_name;
```

For list Page in foreach loop :

```
$attributeSet = $objectManager->create('Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeSetRepositoryInterface');
$attributeSetRepository = $attributeSet->get($product->getAttributeSetId());
$attribute_set_name = $attributeSetRepository->getAttributeSetName();
echo $attribute_set_name;
```

I override list.phtml file in custom module and add "For list page in foreach loop" code.But i got error undefined variable **product**.
How can i resolve this error?
Can you help me?

Comment: i try to get attribute name for products which are in the shopping cart. so i guess i need to use the frist code. my products came in a array. where should i need to put my product array?

Comment: what you want Attribute name or attribute set name?

Comment: attribute set name

Comment: In cart page you can get product object and then try above code it will give you attribute set name